# Angular 2: Apply CSS Style with component selector

Tags: angular, angular2-styleguide

I'm learning Angular 2 and I wonder if it is possible to apply css style by using the component selector like this:

*the component*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    styleUrl: './local.css',
    templateUrl: './app.html',
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

*the style*

```
app {
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Assume it's possible, is it the best way to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean with "best way". Just do it. AFAIK component selector should work (never tried myself though) but `:host` is better practice because it aligns with how webcomponents are styled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `:host` instead

```
:host {
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Use `app` when you want to apply styles from outside the component.

Comment: Ok !! Thanks a lot :)